# Put variable names on diagonal of Seaborn PairGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I put variable names on the diagonal of a Seaborn `PairGrid`, like this from the `PerformanceAnalytics` R package's [`chart.Correlation` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/versions/1.4.3541/topics/chart.Correlation)?

[image]

I imagine this involves a custom function to pass to `map_diag`, but don't know how to extract variable names for it.

For example, this shows the entire array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

def diagfunc(x, **kws):
  ax = plt.gca()
  ax.annotate(x, xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

sns.PairGrid(iris).map_diag(diagfunc)
```

[image: chart attempt using map_diag]

Comment: Indeed, you may use `map_diag` for that purpose. if you have a problem of implementation, you need to provide an example code that allows to reproduce the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original solution here does not work anymore with seaborn >= 0.9. This is due to the change made in [#1464](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/1464), such that from now on the data will be passed as numpy array, which do not have a `name`, instead of a pandas series.

A workaround would be to assume that the order of the axes in the pairgrid follows the order of columns in the dataframe. Then using that order one can iterate over the column names.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')


it = iter(list(df.columns))

def diagfunc(*args, **kws):
    plt.gca().annotate(next(it), xy=(0, 1), xytext=(5,-5), ha="left", va="top", 
                       xycoords=plt.gca().transAxes, textcoords="offset points")

sns.PairGrid(df).map_diag(diagfunc)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this no longer works.*

Use `x.name` in the `map_diag` function, which is passed the series of each column.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

def diagfunc(x, **kws):
  ax = plt.gca()
  ax.annotate(x.name, xy=(0.05, 0.9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

sns.PairGrid(iris).map_diag(diagfunc)
```

[image: plot result]

To also remove the normal axis titles, follow [Remove axis titles from Seaborn PairGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48162182/1840471) and add:

```
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
  ax.set_ylabel('')
  ax.set_xlabel('')
```

[image: plot without axis titles]

Comment: At present the above code provided by you is not working, please modify the code !